Using catalina_globalrequestprocessor_requestcount over time as a metric for custom metric HPA
Is there a way to use catalina_globalrequestprocessor_requestcount metric (or another MBean metric) to track requests as a rate (e.g., requests per second) for use with HPA?
Background
We're using an HPA (Horizontal Pod Autoscaler) with custom metrics in a Java application running on GKE. The setup is as follows:

We deploy the JMX agent to expose MBean metrics from the Tomcat application.
Managed Prometheus is configured to collect these metrics.
The Stackdriver adapter allows the HPA to leverage these custom metrics for scaling decisions.

So far, this setup has worked well, and we've seen positive results using metrics like heap size and thread counts.
Challenge: Using Request Metrics for HPA
We want to scale based on the number of incoming requests, so we tried using the catalina_globalrequestprocessor_requestcount metric as a threshold.
However, this approach didn't work because the metric is cumulative—it tracks the total number of requests from the start and keeps increasing over time. This monotonic increase means the metric will eventually exceed the threshold, even during normal load levels without any actual traffic spike.
Example Issue
Below is a graph from the Google Cloud Metrics Explorer showing the catalina_globalrequestprocessor_requestcount metric's constant upward trend:

What We've Tried
We experimented with the following metric configurations:

prometheus.googleapis.com/catalina_globalrequestprocessor_requestcount/unknown
prometheus.googleapis.com/catalina_globalrequestprocessor_requestcount/unknown:counter

Both configurations exhibited the same increasing behavior.
Question
Is there a way to use this metric (or another MBean metric) to track requests as a rate (e.g., requests per second) for use with HPA?
HPA Configuration Example
Here's an example of the HPA object we used:
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-autoscale
  namespace: my-ns
spec:
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
  - pods:
      metric:
        name: prometheus.googleapis.com|catalina_globalrequestprocessor_requestcount|unknown:counter
      target:
        averageValue: 200
        type: AverageValue
    type: Pods
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-deployment


Have you tried using rate metrics from prometheus already?

rate(catalina_globalrequestprocessor_requestcount[1m])

This metric calculates the requests per second based on changes over a 1-minute window. This rate is suitable for capturing recent changes without being overly sensitive to short-lived fluctuations.
Define the Rate in Prometheus: First, configure a new Prometheus metric based on the rate() function. You want a per-second rate based on a 1-minute interval, so use the following query in Prometheus:
Ensure that Prometheus exports this new rate metric to Google Cloud Managed Prometheus.
Modify the HPA YAML Configuration, That is update your HPA to refer to this rate-based metric.
